# How to setup iOS Automation using Python + Appium + Xcode?

Tags: python, ios, xcode, automation, appium

I have been struggling with this for a few days now...My biggest problem is navigating Xcode and setting up a project where I can actually begin writing python scripts. I am not creating an app and then deploying that app, I simply want to test an existing app on a real iOS device. Can anyone please provide some insight? Thank you!

Comment: http://ericasadun.com/2016/12/04/running-python-in-xcode-step-by-step/

Comment: I am currently following this guide, but am having trouble selecting python2.7 as the executable. Also, this does not get into certificates etc.

Comment: https://vandadnp.wordpress.com/2014/10/20/building-and-running-python-scripts-with-xcode-6-1/  -- I had better luck with this..but where do I go from here??